# Find areas of points which share similar intensity

Tags: r, gis, spatial

This is probably very simple and if that proves to be true, I will remove this post.

I have researched this answer quite a bit, but I am not well versed with spatial analysis terms.

My data consists of a mean score column, a x coordinate, and an y coordinate. Scores range from 0-50.

I want identify areas of similar intensity (mean score < 20) in this data. Something similar to nearest-neighbor, but producing hubs of poor scores. Not all data within those hubs will be poor scores; however, the majority will (95%). I then would like to remove those areas from my dataset.

I realize I have asked multiple requests in this post, but simply identifying poor regions would be the biggest help. I have looked into heatmaps and simply plotting a matrix made up of the scores; however, heatmaps are not well suited for my data (I think?) and image plotting only provides each point colored by its score rather than a region of similar values.

I can probably figure the code out, but I am at a loss for terms to search to be honest. What would one call what I am looking for? I am leaning kernel smoothing or nearest neighbor analysis right now.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe, I don't understand your question, but can't you just do `subset(data, mean_column <= 20)`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already done this however. If I go with this approach, how would one identify the areas of correlation? Viewing a plot works well to visual interpret the results; however, how would would draw centriods or the like around these zones? Could their perhaps be a better way without using a hard coded value (20)? I know I specified that originally; however, if I could avoid this it would work better down the road.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at `spatstat` functions `Smooth` (note uppercase S) and `cut.im`.

Generate artificial data.frame with x, y and "score" columns (actually locations and diameters of trees):

```
library(spatstat)
x <- as.data.frame(longleaf)
```

Convert to `ppp` object:

```
W <- boundingbox(x)
X <- as.ppp(x, W=W)
```

Smooth values and cut them into regions:

```
i <- Smooth(X)
regions <- cut(i, breaks = 5)
plot(regions)
```

Comment: This definitely put me on the proper path. I am still working out some of the code, but I am making major progress. Once I get things worked out properly, I will post my answer. Thank you for your help as it has lead me down the road I am currently on.